# A more logical approach to a word problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

I was taught in high school algebra to translate word problems into algebraic expressions. So when I encountered [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2016_AMC_10A_Problems/Problem_3) problem I tried to reason out an algebra formula for it

> For every dollar Ben spent on bagels, David spent 25 cents less. Ben
> paid $12.50 more than David. How much did they spend in the bagel store
> together?

To solve this I imagined a series of comparisons when Ben spends $x$, David spends $.75x$. Loop this relationship until $x - .75x \approx 12.50$. Good. Done. $x = 50$, then add David's for the answer. Coming from computers, I would have set this up in code where a loop (recursion) would increase $x$ until the condition $x - .75x = 12.50$ was met, then the "loop counter/accumulator" would be how much Ben spent, i.e., $50$, etc.

I'm a beginner with math, but it seems like there should be a better approach, something with series and sequences or even calculus derivatives, something better than my brute-force computer algorithm. Can someone enlighten? The "answer" given at the site (see link) is its own brute-force and hardly satisfying. I'm thinking there should be something more formal -- at least for the first part that derives $50$.

**Update**

I think everyone so far has missed my point. Many of you simply re-did the problem again. I'm wondering if there is a more *formal* way to do this other than just "figuring it out" (FIO). The whole FIO routine is murky. It looks like a limit problem; it looks like a system of equations, but I'm not experienced enough to know exactly. If there isn't, then let's call it a day....

Answer (score 3):

From the step $x-.75x=12.50$ simplify to $.25x=12.5$,  divide by .25  to immediately get $x=50$.  No looping/brute force needed.

Comment: I guess the whole point of word problems is to give real-world examples of applied algebra. But "jumping" with strong intuitive legs to this answer is not very formal math-like. I'm trying to get to Formal-land with this.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, with no $x$'s needed:

The first condition says the difference between their spending is $1/4$ of what Ben spends.  That difference is $\$12.50$, so Ben's amount is $4 \times \$ 12.50 = \$50$.

Answer (score 1):

If the difference is $\$12.50$ then it must be the product of dollars times $\$0.25$ so we divide:
$\quad\dfrac{12.50}{0.25}=50\quad$ for Ben and another $\quad 37.50 \quad$ for David for a total of $\quad\$87.50$

Answer (score 0):

You can use linear algebra, by defining something as x, say the amount paid by Ben. Then Dave's will be 0.75x. Then we can get an easily solvable equation.

Comment: I'm not, but imagine I'm a high school kid. What do you mean by linear algebra here?

Comment: "linear algebra" means "algebra" where the equations have $x$ to a single power $ax + b = m$ so $ax = m-b$ so $x = \frac {m-b}a$... No need to worry about $x^2$s or anything..  I am having a very hard time understand what your question or difficulty is.  Have you *never* been taught how to solve algebraic equations by "unwrapping them"?  $ax - bx = c \implies (a-b)x = c\implies x = \frac c{a-b}$.  I can't *imagine* doing that by "loop" or "brute force".

Comment: @fleablood: Maybe yes, maybe no. But after years in the programming world, no, we typically just throw a loop at problems like this and then whatever the counter says is the answer. LOL

Comment: I have a hard time even understanding what you *mean* by "loop".  So how would you solve $7x + 3=45$ by loop?   Do you start at $x = 1$ and get $7x+3=10$? and move to $x=2$ and and get $18$? and... what?   Or do you jumbe $x=10$ and get $73$ as that's to big go to $x=5$ or .... I don't get it... what *are* you doing?  Why *aren't* you simply solving for $x$?  $7x + 3 = 45$ so $7x = 45-3=42$ and $x=\frac {42}7 = 6$? I *really* don't understand what the issue is here.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit I'm having a hard time seeing how you "imagine a series of comparisons " and how you "loop" them.

As a mathematician, I simply view this as Ben did a *single* transaction where in one go he spent $x$ dollars on bagels.

Therefore David spend $0.75x$ on bagels (in one go).

Set *one* equation (no series of loops) to get $x - 0.75x = 12.50$ and solve:

> $x-0.75x = 12.50$
> $0.25x = 12.50$
> $\frac {0.25}{0.25} x = \frac {12.50}{0.25}$
> $x = 50$

So Ben spent $50$ dollars on bagels.

Now add Davids answer.  David spent $0.75x$ and $x = 50$ so David spent $0.75 \times 50 = 37.50$.  Adding that they added $50+37.50 = 87.50$.

Or.... Ben spent $x$ and David spent $0.75x$ so together they spent $x + 0.75x = 1.75x$ and as $x = 50$ together they spent $1.75\times 50 = 87.50$.